# Powershell stopping services with dependencies

Tags: powershell, service

cannot understand why I can't stop a service with the powershell 'stop-service' as I can stop it with the 'net stop' command.

The service has one dependent service which is stopped (not a synchronization problem, I've tested 10 minutes after having stopped the dependent service).

Sorry for the french version of output...

```
PS C:\> stop-service pgsql-8.3
Stop-Service : Impossible d'arrêter le service « PostgreSQL Database Server 8.3 (pgsql-8.3) », car d'autres services en dépendent. Il peut être arrêté uniquement si l'indicateur Force est défini.
Au niveau de ligne : 1 Caractère : 13
+ stop-service <<<<  pgsql-8.3
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.ServiceProcess.Service
   Controller:ServiceController) [Stop-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ServiceHasDependentServices,Microsoft.PowerShell
   .Commands.StopServiceCommand

PS C:\> net stop pgsql-8.3
Le service PostgreSQL Database Server 8.3 s'arrête.
Le service PostgreSQL Database Server 8.3 a été arrêté.
```

The only way suggested by powershell is to force the stop. Is there a way to avoid this behaviour ?

Thanks in advance.

Denis

Comment: hm, you could try to use `cmd /c sc stop pgsql-8.3`

Comment: I use PowerShell because I want to check results and possible errors. Using a cmd command can lead me to parse results, thing I don't want to do. Please not that my question was about avoiding the two behaviours not to find a workaround (solved with net stop, as I mentioned). Sorry to have not said that I work on a big powershell script. My example was to ease the understanding.

Comment: `sc stop <service name>` merely says _A stop control has been sent to a service that other running services are dependent on._; `stop-service <service name>` fail stopping a service (as described above) while `net stop <service name>` prompts me _… Stopping the <service display name> will also stop these services. `<dependent service display name>` Do you want to continue this operation? (Y/N) [N]:_  but **only if a dependent service state is _running_**. Otherwise, all `net stop`, `sc stop` and PowerShell's `stop-service` would stop a service almost immediately. Windows 8.1 and PowerShell 4.0

Comment: @JosefZ On my Windows 2008r2 with PowerShell V.2, it does not work like this.

Comment: Check `(Get-Service -Include 'pgsql-8.3').DependentServices | %{$_}`. BTW, why don't you follow advised `stop-service 'pgsql-8.3' -force`?

Comment: According to me, using the 'force' (like a padawan...) means that things don't work as you want, thus ignoring important messages that could be returned by the function querying the service state.

Answer (score 1):

## Recommended solution

### Docs state that -Force is used for stopping a service *and* DependentServices

#### [Stop-Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-service?view=powershell-7.1)

```
Stop-Service 'pgsql-8.3' -Force
```

## Alternate solution

### Pipe the DependentServices to Stop-Service to stop them first

Get-Service 'pgsql-8.3' -DependentServices | Stop-Service -Verbose

### Get the DependentServices again to check they stopped

```
Get-Service 'pgsql-8.3' -DependentServices
```

### Now the service should stop without -Force

```
Stop-Service 'pgsql-8.3' -Verbose
```

## Starting should also start DependentServices

```
Start-Service 'pgsql-8.3' -Verbose
```